# Pandas groupby then fill missing rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe structured like this:

df_all:

```
      day_time            LCLid       energy(kWh/hh)
2014-02-08 23:00:00     MAC000006         0.077
2014-02-08 23:30:00     MAC000006         0.079
        ...
2014-02-08 23:00:00     MAC000007         0.045
        ...
```

There are four sequential datetimes (accross all LCLid's) missing from the data that I want to fill with previous and trailing values.

If the dataframe was split into sub-dataframes (df), one per LCLid eg as per:

```
gb = df.groupby('LCLid')    
df_list = [gb.get_group(x) for x in gb.groups]
```

Then I could do this for each df in df_list:

```
#valid data before gap
prev_row = df.loc['2013-09-09 22:30:00'].copy()
#valid data after gap
post_row = df.loc['2013-09-10 01:00:00'].copy()
df.loc[pd.to_datetime('2013-09-09 23:00:00')] = prev_row
df.loc[pd.to_datetime('2013-09-09 23:30:00')] = prev_row
df.loc[pd.to_datetime('2013-09-10 00:00:00')] = post_row
df.loc[pd.to_datetime('2013-09-10 00:30:00')] = post_row

df = df.sort_index()
```

How can I do this on the df_all one one go to fill the missing data with 'valid' data just from each LCLid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The solution

The input DataFrame:

```
                         LCLid  energy(kWh/hh)
day_time                                      
2014-01-01 00:00:00  MAC000006        0.270453
2014-01-01 00:00:00  MAC000007        0.170603
2014-01-01 00:30:00  MAC000006        0.716418
2014-01-01 00:30:00  MAC000007        0.276678
2014-01-01 03:00:00  MAC000006        0.819146
2014-01-01 03:00:00  MAC000007        0.027490
2014-01-01 03:30:00  MAC000006        0.688879
2014-01-01 03:30:00  MAC000007        0.868017
```

What you need to do:

```
full_idx = pd.date_range(start=df.index.min(), end=df.index.max(), freq='30T')
df = (
    df
    .groupby('LCLid', as_index=False)  
    .apply(lambda group: group.reindex(full_idx, method='nearest'))  
    .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)  
    .sort_index()  
)
```

Result:

```
                         LCLid  energy(kWh/hh)
2014-01-01 00:00:00  MAC000006        0.270453
2014-01-01 00:00:00  MAC000007        0.170603
2014-01-01 00:30:00  MAC000006        0.716418
2014-01-01 00:30:00  MAC000007        0.276678
2014-01-01 01:00:00  MAC000006        0.716418
2014-01-01 01:00:00  MAC000007        0.276678
2014-01-01 01:30:00  MAC000006        0.716418
2014-01-01 01:30:00  MAC000007        0.276678
2014-01-01 02:00:00  MAC000006        0.819146
2014-01-01 02:00:00  MAC000007        0.027490
2014-01-01 02:30:00  MAC000006        0.819146
2014-01-01 02:30:00  MAC000007        0.027490
2014-01-01 03:00:00  MAC000006        0.819146
2014-01-01 03:00:00  MAC000007        0.027490
2014-01-01 03:30:00  MAC000006        0.688879
2014-01-01 03:30:00  MAC000007        0.868017
```

---

## The explanation

#### First I'll build an example DataFrame that looks like yours

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


# Building an example DataFrame that looks like yours
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'day_time': [
           pd.Timestamp(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0),
           pd.Timestamp(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0),
           pd.Timestamp(2014, 1, 1, 0, 30),
           pd.Timestamp(2014, 1, 1, 0, 30),
           pd.Timestamp(2014, 1, 1, 3, 0),
           pd.Timestamp(2014, 1, 1, 3, 0),
           pd.Timestamp(2014, 1, 1, 3, 30),
           pd.Timestamp(2014, 1, 1, 3, 30),
        ],
        'LCLid': [
            'MAC000006',
            'MAC000007',
            'MAC000006',
            'MAC000007',
            'MAC000006',
            'MAC000007',
            'MAC000006',
            'MAC000007',
        ],
        'energy(kWh/hh)': np.random.rand(8)
    },
).set_index('day_time')
```

Result:

```
                         LCLid  energy(kWh/hh)
day_time
2014-01-01 00:00:00  MAC000006        0.270453
2014-01-01 00:00:00  MAC000007        0.170603
2014-01-01 00:30:00  MAC000006        0.716418
2014-01-01 00:30:00  MAC000007        0.276678
2014-01-01 03:00:00  MAC000006        0.819146
2014-01-01 03:00:00  MAC000007        0.027490
2014-01-01 03:30:00  MAC000006        0.688879
2014-01-01 03:30:00  MAC000007        0.868017
```

Notice how we're missing the following timestamps:

```
2014-01-01 01:00:00
2014-01-01 01:30:00
2014-01-02 02:00:00
2014-01-02 02:30:00
```

#### df.reindex()

First thing to know is that `df.reindex()` allows you to fill in missing index values, and will default to `NaN` for missing values. In your case, you would want to supply the full timestamp range index, including the values that don't show up in your starting DataFrame.

Here I used `pd.date_range()` to list all timestamps between your min and max starting index values, taking strides of 30 minutes. **WARNING**: this way of doing it means that if your missing timestamp values are at the beginning or the end, you're not adding them back! So maybe you want to specify `start` and `end` explicitly.

```
full_idx = pd.date_range(start=df.index.min(), end=df.index.max(), freq='30T')
```

Result:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2014-01-01 00:00:00', '2014-01-01 00:30:00',
               '2014-01-01 01:00:00', '2014-01-01 01:30:00',
               '2014-01-01 02:00:00', '2014-01-01 02:30:00',
               '2014-01-01 03:00:00', '2014-01-01 03:30:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='30T')
```

Now if we use that to reindex one of your grouped sub-DataFrames, we would get this:

```
grouped_df = df[df.LCLid == 'MAC000006']
grouped_df.reindex(full_idx)
```

Result:

```
                         LCLid  energy(kWh/hh)
2014-01-01 00:00:00  MAC000006        0.270453
2014-01-01 00:30:00  MAC000006        0.716418
2014-01-01 01:00:00        NaN             NaN
2014-01-01 01:30:00        NaN             NaN
2014-01-01 02:00:00        NaN             NaN
2014-01-01 02:30:00        NaN             NaN
2014-01-01 03:00:00  MAC000006        0.819146
2014-01-01 03:30:00  MAC000006        0.688879
```

You said you want to fill missing values using the closest available surrounding value. This can be done during reindexing, as follows:

```
grouped_df.reindex(full_idx, method='nearest')
```

Result:

```
                         LCLid  energy(kWh/hh)
2014-01-01 00:00:00  MAC000006        0.270453
2014-01-01 00:30:00  MAC000006        0.716418
2014-01-01 01:00:00  MAC000006        0.716418
2014-01-01 01:30:00  MAC000006        0.716418
2014-01-01 02:00:00  MAC000006        0.819146
2014-01-01 02:30:00  MAC000006        0.819146
2014-01-01 03:00:00  MAC000006        0.819146
2014-01-01 03:30:00  MAC000006        0.688879
```

#### Doing all the groups at once using df.groupby()

Now we'd like to apply this transformation to every group in your DataFrame, where
a group is defined by its `LCLid`.

```
(
    df
    .groupby('LCLid', as_index=False)  # use LCLid as groupby key, but don't add it as a group index
    .apply(lambda group: group.reindex(full_idx, method='nearest'))  # do this for each group
    .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)  # get rid of the automatic index generated during groupby
    .sort_index()  # This is optional, just in case you want timestamps in chronological order
)
```

Result:

```
                         LCLid  energy(kWh/hh)
2014-01-01 00:00:00  MAC000006        0.270453
2014-01-01 00:00:00  MAC000007        0.170603
2014-01-01 00:30:00  MAC000006        0.716418
2014-01-01 00:30:00  MAC000007        0.276678
2014-01-01 01:00:00  MAC000006        0.716418
2014-01-01 01:00:00  MAC000007        0.276678
2014-01-01 01:30:00  MAC000006        0.716418
2014-01-01 01:30:00  MAC000007        0.276678
2014-01-01 02:00:00  MAC000006        0.819146
2014-01-01 02:00:00  MAC000007        0.027490
2014-01-01 02:30:00  MAC000006        0.819146
2014-01-01 02:30:00  MAC000007        0.027490
2014-01-01 03:00:00  MAC000006        0.819146
2014-01-01 03:00:00  MAC000007        0.027490
2014-01-01 03:30:00  MAC000006        0.688879
2014-01-01 03:30:00  MAC000007        0.868017
```

---

Relevant doc:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html